# automatically start typing in tkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I'm trying to make a input screen with Tkinter that will when i type automatically receive my input without me having to click it first. would this be possible?
I wasn't able to find a tutorial or text document online to do this, and hope someone can help me with this problem! I'm on Windows 10 (bootcamped on a mac) with Python 3.8.3 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is called "focus". When you type, the widget with the focus will receive the keypress events. So, to let you immediately type into an entry widget, force the UI to set the focus to that widget by using `focus_set`:

```
the_entry = Entry(root, ...)
the_entry.focus_set()
```

When the window as a whole is focused (ie: brought to the front), this will cause the keyboard focus to be set to the entry widget.